# jquery onHover capture a css value from a click event?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that I am trying to implement which you can see on jsbin

http://jsbin.com/uvetaw/5

How can I make it so that opacity is always 1 if a link is clicked in an article that was opacity 0.5 when hovered into it?

Answer (score 2):

Append, toggle, or remove classes with a hierarchy
The question is kinda vague, so I hope this helps.

```
.hovered-div {
  opacity: 0.5
}

.clicked-div {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**Update**

Javascript:

```
$("article").hover(
    function () {
      $(this).removeClass('hovered', 1000);
    },
    function () {
      $(this).addClass('hovered', 1000);
    }
  );

$('a[rel="article"]').click(function() {
  $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked', 1000);
  $(this).parents('article').addClass('clicked', 1000);
});
```

CSS:

```
.hovered {opacity:0.5}
.clicked {opacity:1 !important}
```

Use jQueryUI to support the transitions.

Comment: You may want to look into HoverIntent, at first glance of your JS http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: Edited. Tested working with your code (not transitions, but you can use jQueryUI for that)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the hover in the click event like this :

```
$(".open").unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
```

or this :

```
$(".open").unbind('mouseenter').off('hover');
```

Comment: yeah but you only unbind it on the open article, and rebind it when you close it ... well the other solution is certainly better ;)